# Xcode - How do I find my .app file?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

The common answer I keep getting is that the file is in `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/{app name}/Build/Products/Deployment/...`

But when I navigate to **Library/Developer** there is no Xcode folder. There is only a folder called CommandLineTools. I also searched for an Xcode folder using Go -> Go to folder, but that returned no results. (Even though that often returns no results even when I search a folder name that I know very well exists.)

Answer (score 3):

You can right click on the file in Xcode file browser and click `Show in Finder`.

[image]

P.S. If you are trying to submit the app to the App Store, this is not what you would usually do.

Comment: That option isn't available for me. Its greyed out. I've read that there is some bug that keeps people from accessing the .app file from within Xcode using that method. And I'm not trying to submit anything either.

Answer (score 2):

By far the easiest solution would be the answer by Enrico.
But since is it not available to you there are still some other possibilities.

1. Start Xcode
2. Open the Organizer: Window -> Organizer or <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd>
3. Select the projects tab
4. Find your project in the left sidebar
5. In the main window there is a row „Derived Data“ with a small arrow at the end.
6. Press the small arrow
7. Done

[image: Xcode Organizer Window]